# Twilio SMS body doesn't concatenate URL parameters in Azure Logic App

Tags: android, azure, sms, twilio, azure-logic-apps

I'm currently building a logic app in Azure to send text messages with Twilio. Everything is working smoothly except that I can't send complex URL in the body.

For exemple if I send this : https://example.com?id=26 I will recieve the the correct string, but the parameter is not concatenated correctly with the domain in the clickable link. 
[image]

So when I click the link in the text message it only opens the https://example.com . The message I'm sending is built like this :

```
 "Send_Text_Message_(SMS)": {
            "inputs": {
                "body": {
                    "body": "@{triggerBody()?['message']}@{triggerBody()?['url']}@{body('Insert_row')?['Id']}",
                    "from": "xxx-xxx-xxxx",
                    "to": "@triggerBody()?['phone']"
                },

message: Hello please click this link
url :https://example.com?id=
id: 26
so the final body would be like : [message][url][id]
```

I've tried sending a simple string like https://example.com?id=8 to see if it was the "complex" body concatenation that was failing, but it's still not working.

Can anyone help :) ?

Comment: Are you able to send a text message from a regular phone with a complex link in it?

Comment: Ok, so I had a friend text it to me and I have the same behavior... So it's more on Android's side I guess ??

Comment: Yup, looks like it. Nothing Twilio can do I'm afraid.

Comment: @philnash I found an answer if you're curious :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone that would be stuck with this here's how I tricked android :

I added a / after the .com so now the url I'm sending is :

https://example.com/?id=36

[image]